# Arch Linux frozen on Macbook Pro (12,1) while playing video?

Tags: arch-linux, macintosh

I had a Macbook Pro early 2015 (12,1).
Successfully installed Arch Linux on it, but one problem that I faced is frozen. As normal use, surfing  the internet, use command line have no problem. However when I watching movie about 30 minutes, this problem had occurred, it frozen and the sound repeat endlessly. Everything is die, unable to move the cursor and change tty console.
I have to force reboot in order to use it again. 
Therefore I don't know which log had been log when this problem occurred and please suggest me which log should I post.

Kernel: 5.2.3-arch1-1-ARCH
Player app: I played movie via Firefox

lsmod:

```
https://gist.github.com/mrhieu059/2284f09147350c14f74f0cd9a6c0b989
```

lspci:

```
https://gist.github.com/mrhieu059/be68df055148a378dda10e1e849f1dc6
```

Comment: What happens when you use the stock standard ARCH Linux kernel, 5.1.5 https://www.archlinux.org/download/ ? Which movie player are you using? Please advise; click [edit] and add the name of the player app to your question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, add it into the question with [edit] .

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I updated the information needed. I didn't try other kernel version since I install Linux on this machine. I'll try it out and report it when I have free time

Comment: Also, you might try VLC https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VLC_media_player and smplayer instead of mplayer. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MPlayer#SMPlayer:_No_video_issue

Comment: I been using Mpv ever since, also the problem seem like not occur with Mpv, didn't test with it. I'll test it now and report it if it still occur on Mpv. But thank you for suggest me VLC and SMplayer